# How do you recompile a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, directory, executable-jar

I took an old jar file and edited it. Now i have a folder that has all the files and I want to recompile them back to a jar file. How do i do this?

Comment: you had .java files in the jar?

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6604097/2881888

Answer (score 11):

Jar files aren't "compiled" in the normal sense of the word. But you just create one with the `jar` command:

```
jar cvf myfile.jar file1 file2 etc
```

You can use globbing as normal:

```
jar cvf ../myfile.jar *
```

Run `jar -?` or read the [docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jar.html) for more information.

Note that for an executable jar file, you'll need to specify the manifest file as well.

Answer (score 7):

How did you edit it?

Anyway, `jar` files follow the same format as regular `zip` files. If you want to update the content of the jar ( probably with a new file ) you could do:

```
jar -uf yourJar.jar  path/to/updated/Class.class
```

That would update your jar with the file `path/to/updated/Class.class` If there's already a class with that name in that path, it would be replaced. If is not it would be created.

After this your jar is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Jar files usually contain compiled java files (class-files) and resources.
If you are allowed to make changes on this jar, you could disassemble the class files using [JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad) and after recompilation assemble them again with the command [jar](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html)

How did you edit a jar file, hex editor?

Answer (score 1):

A jar file is just a zip file with a few extra files. You Can use any zip utility to rejar an unjarred jar file.