# How to edit code inside a jar?

Tags: java, jar, decompiling, reflector, reflexil

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing the code of the class from jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848161/changing-the-code-of-the-class-from-jar-file)

I'm coming with this from .Net, where there's Reflector and Reflexil, enabling me to open an assembly and edit its code without having to re-compile it. I did some research, and I've found  jd-gui, which lets me view java code inside a jar, but I can't find anything that resembles reflexil.

Is there any software which would let me modify jars without having to re-compile them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A jar is just a zip, actually, so there's no recompiling. Just unjar it (using jar xf), add, replace or delete some files or directories, and jar it again (using jar cf).

Comment: Yes, jar is just an archive, but it may contain binary .class files. How do I deal with that? Can I simply replace the binary .class files with .java files?

Comment: @ArsenZahray Yes, and no. You can replace .class file only with another .class file. Use: javac nameofjavafile.java to compile your .java file to .class file. Than jar it again.

Comment: how ho I compile the .java file, if the class inside it references other classes inside the jar?

Comment: Use: javac -classpath /some/path/your.jar yourfile.java yourfile2.java ...